# Error:conversion from string load report failed to type integer is not valid

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

there is one search button to see the report on datagridview using year..so when the more items are there in database correspond it year(say 2012)... the above exception is thrown by filling the datgridview,the problem happens when it tries to connect with crystal report,it shows error...Remember that i face this problem only if there are more records in my database(exactly more than 100 rows)...when i delete few rows from the database,it works fine..I have created a table and added that table to a dataset,then assigned that table1 as datasource for crystal report

```
Public Class crystalform1

Dim r As DataRow
Dim t As DataTable
Dim ds1 As New DataSet1()
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.



    t = ds1.Tables.Add("DataTable1")


    t.Columns.Add("invoiceno", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("customer_name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("customer_phonenumber", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("date", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("product_item", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("bookno", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("serialno", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("price", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
    t.Columns.Add("quantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

    t.Columns.Add("discount", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

    t.Columns.Add("paymentby", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("checkno", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("checkdate", Type.GetType(" System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("total", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
    t.Columns.Add("totalamount", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
End Sub
 Sub formcall(ByVal invoiceno As Integer, ByVal date1 As Date, ByVal customername As String, ByVal customerphone As Integer, ByVal product As String, ByVal bookno As Integer, ByVal serialno As Integer, ByVal price As Single, ByVal quantity As Integer, ByVal discount As Integer, ByVal payment As String, ByVal checkno As Integer, ByVal checkdate As String, ByVal total As Single, ByVal totalamount As Single)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    If IsDate(checkdate) Then
        CType(checkdate, Date).ToShortDateString()
    End If


    r = t.NewRow()
    r("invoiceno") = invoiceno
    r("customer_Name") = customername
    r("customer_Phonenumber") = customerphone
    r("date") = date1.ToShortDateString
    r("product_item") = product
    r("bookNo") = bookno
    r("serialNo") = serialno
    r("price") = price
    r("quantity") = quantity
    r("discount") = discount
    r("paymentby") = payment
    r("checkno") = checkno
    r("checkdate") = checkdate
    r("total") = total
    r("totalamount") = totalamount

    t.Rows.Add(r)
    Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport2


 Try
            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(1))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt /*exception is showing here*/
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Report Error", ex.Message())
        End Try



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself,Here the problem was ,if there are more data on database,my crystal report will be loaded that many times,because i have set datasource of crystal report inside formcall() method,this method is calling more than 100 times when each row add to table,so this same report is loading that many times.I declared the "setDatasource(ds.table(1))" in new method which is called by a click_button event only after added all row into the datasource table..thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment all this lines

```
r("invoiceno") = invoiceno
r("customer_Name") = customername
r("customer_Phonenumber") = customerphone
r("date") = date1.ToShortDateString
r("product_item") = product
r("bookNo") = bookno
r("serialNo") = serialno
r("price") = price
r("quantity") = quantity
r("discount") = discount
r("paymentby") = payment
r("checkno") = checkno
r("checkdate") = checkdate
r("total") = total
r("totalamount") = totalamount
```

and then uncomment one by one.

Comment: i uncommented even all of above,Still it is showing the same error,even it is blank (ie.     t = ds1.Tables.Add("DataTable1")
        r = t.NewRow() t.Rows.Add(r)
        Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport2) all r("xx..")and  t.Columns.Add("invoiceno", Type.GetType("xxx")) uncommented

Comment: Problem is happening when add new row to datatable more than 100 times(more than 100 rows)